# What is the difference TO_DATE('21-09-1989','DD-MM-YY') and TO_DATE('21-09-89','DD-MM-YY')?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, format, y2k

Below query returns the result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMPLOYEES 
WHERE HIRE_DATE = TO_DATE('21-09-1989','DD-MM-YY');
```

where as if I change the date from 21-09-1989 to 21-09-89 returns nothing.

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMPLOYEES 
WHERE HIRE_DATE = TO_DATE('21-09-89','DD-MM-YY');
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: That's how the Y2K bug was introduced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use the `YY` as the year then it returns the year which is in the current century i.e. `2000-2099`. In your case `-- 2089`

If you use the `YYYY` then the exact year is returned. -- in your case `1989`

If you use `RR` then the year which is between `1950-2049` is returned. -- in your case `1989`

So

```
TO_DATE('21-09-1989','DD-MM-YY') --> 21-09-1989
-- oracle is smart to detect the given format as YYYY

TO_DATE('21-09-89','DD-MM-YY') --> 21-09-2089
-- as 2089 is between 2000-2099

TO_DATE('21-09-89','DD-MM-RR') --> 21-09-1989
-- as 1989 is between 1950-2049
```

Answer (score 3):

```
TO_DATE('21-09-89','DD-MM-YY')
```

evaluates to Sep 21 2089

Answer (score 0):

As already explained in other answer about the difference between `'YY'` and `'YYYY'` format and its implications. You could easily avoid problems by using the **ANSI DATE literal**:

```
DATE '1989-09-21'
```

The ANSI date literal contains no time portion, and must be specified in exactly this format `('YYYY-MM-DD')`.

Also, `HIRE_DATE` is a **DATE data type** which also has a **time portion**. Therefore, your WHERE condition might not return correct values:

```
WHERE HIRE_DATE = TO_DATE('21-09-1989','DD-MM-YY')
```

To remove the time portion you must use **TRUNC** to compare with only date portion:

```
WHERE TRUNC(HIRE_DATE) = DATE '1989-09-21'
```

Comment: The "issue" here is _exactly_ what the Y2k bug was all about . . .

Comment: I agree Ed. I just added some more points as they are important too.

Comment: Very true, Lalit.  We're not at cross-purposes here.  You gave the OP the technical fix and reasoning.  I was merely making the point (really, directed to the OP) that this entire issue flows from not learning lessons of 20 years ago.  It's increasingly apparent that somehow those lessons are not being passed on to the next generation.  I would hope that as they re-learn it, what they learn is the fundamental of don't ever use 2-digit years.  But I'm losing hope on that front as well, as I continue to see reliance on short-cuts.

Comment: You're absolutely right, Ed. You made a very good point that the lesson we learnt in the late 90s didn't pass along to next generation. 20 years back it was a nightmare when the consequnces of using 2 digit years dawned upon the engineers and costed millions to fix the systems. This generation is inclined more towards shortcuts and have no clarity on fundamentals.